# rgba() is producing a blackish tone in HTML5 Canvas Gradient

Tags: html5-canvas, rgb, rgba

I wanted to draw three gradients on top of the other on a HTML5 Canvas. But it wasn't not producing the desired effect. So I dug into the thing a little bit, and found out that `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` was not completely transparent when used in canvas gradient. Rather it was producing an unexpected blackish tone.

In CSS, it works fine though.

How can I have the same effect as it works in CSS? (see attached screenshot please)

CSS properties:

```
background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgb(255, 0, 0));
```

Canvas properties:

```
var grad = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, height);
    grad.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)');
    grad.addColorStop(1, 'rgb(255, 0, 0)');
```

[image: rgba() in CSS vs HTML5 Canvas]

Comment: When adding the transparent gradient stop, specify the color as transparent red. rgba(255, 0, 0, 0). That will make it look like CSS. The two have different specs and behave differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed the algorithms seem to be different.

Not quite sure why, but I'd say that CSS doesn't consider `rgba(0,0,0,0)` as **transparent black pixel** like canvas does, but instead just as *transparent*.

The 2D canvas will composite straight from all the 4 RGBA channels values, until the ones of the next stop, while CSS one seems to comprehend transparent as a particular case.

To get the same result as CSS on a canvas, you'd have to set your first transparent stop to the next one, by only changing the alpha value:

```js
var ctx = c.getContext('2d'),
  grad = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,150);
grad.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(255,0,0,0)'); // transparent red
grad.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(255,0,0)');
ctx.fillStyle = grad;
ctx.fillRect(0,0,300,150);
```

```css
#html{
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgb(255, 0, 0));
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="html"></div>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```